# Cannot get images or text centred

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am creating a portfolio website for myself, but the recent projects and companies I have working for sections are supposed to be centred but I can't get them centred.

How can I fix the code? I'm not good with technical programming words.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <link rel="icon" href="assets/img/favicon.ico">

    <title>Jacob Lane - Portfolio</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="assets/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
    <link href="assets/css/ionicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="assets/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">


    <!-- IE10 viewport hack for Surface/desktop Windows 8 bug -->
    <script src="assets/js/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.js"></script>

    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
</head>

<body>

    <div id="h">
        <div class="logo">
            <h2>PHOTOGRAPHY</h2>
        </div>
        <!--/logo-->
        <div class="container centered">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
                    <h1>Hello, my name is <b>Jacob Lane</b>.<br/>Enjoy. :)</h1>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!--/row-->

            <div class="row mt">
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <i class="ion-ios7-copy-outline"></i>
                    <h3>Secure Photos</h3>
                </div>
                <!--/col-md-4-->

                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <i class="ion-monitor"></i>
                    <h3>Professionally Edited</h3>
                </div>
                <!--/col-md-4-->

                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <i class="ion-camera"></i>
                    <h3>Professionally Taken</h3>
                </div>
                <!--/col-md-4-->

            </div>
            <!--/row-->
        </div>
        <!--/container-->
    </div>
    <!--H-->

    <div class="container ptb">
        <div class="row">
            <h2 class="centered mb"><b>My Gear:</b></h2>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <p>To get the best shot in all photos, I use high-quality gear to make sure your memories can last a lifetime. Memories are an extraordinary thing to keep in your lifetime so using the best high-quality gear out it is good for what I offer.</p>
            </div>
            <!--/col-md-6-->
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <p>You can book a trial session or an event session below in the contact my area. Alternatively, you can see the feedback from I have gotten from past customers to get a realistic view of how good my gear can make memories last.</p>
            </div>
            <!--/col-md-6-->
        </div>
        <!--/row-->
    </div>
    <!-- /.container -->
    <div class="container" id="j">
        <div class="row">
                <p class="text-align-center"><strong>My Camera</strong>, Known for its ablilty to have a good photo, the Canon EOS 1200D has a stunning lens to capture high definition moments. I use this camera as it is capable of taking stunning high definition photo's for those
                    beautiful moments in life.</p>
                <a href="https://www.amazon.co.uk/Canon-1200D-Digital-Camera-3-5-5-6/dp/B00IE3UR08/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1468269724&sr=8-1&keywords=canon+eos+1200+d" target="_blank">Canon EOS 1200D</a>
                <p class="text-align-center"><strong>My Lens</strong>, The Lengs on the camera help the camera become more high definition and let me create more stunning zoomed in shots when needed.</p>
                <a href="https://www.amazon.co.uk/Canon-EF-S-18-55mm-3-5-5-6-Zoom/dp/B00BXVR97M/ref=sr_1_2?ie=UTF8&qid=1468269951&sr=8-2&keywords=18-55mm+lens+canon" target="_blank">Canon EF-S 18-55mm f/3.5-5.6 IS STM Zoom Lens</a> //\\ <a href="https://www.amazon.co.uk/Canon-75-300mm-4-0-5-6-III-Lens/dp/B00005K47Y">Canon EF 75-300mm f/4.0-5.6 III Lens</a>
                <p class="text-align-center"><strong>My Tripod</strong>, The allows me to be at the right comfortable height when I am taking photos, it also allows me to take pictures more stable so that the focus is better.</p>
                <a href="https://www.amazon.co.uk/VELBON-EF-51-DIGITAL-CAMERA-TRIPOD/dp/B019ZWAA1M/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1468270490&sr=8-1&keywords=Velbon+EF+-61+tripod" target="_blank">Velbon EF -61 Tripod</a>
            <!--/col-md-6-->
        </div>
        <!--/row-->
    </div>
    <!--/.container-->

    <div id="g">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row centered">
                <h2>Past work:</h2>
                <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
                    <p>Here are some pass work that I have been allowed to put up :)</p>
                </div>
                <!--/col-md-8-->
            </div>
            <!--/row-->
        </div>
        <!--/.container-->
        <div class="portfolio-centered mt">
            <div class="recentitems portfolio">
                <div class="portfolio-item graphic-design">
                    <div class="he-wrap tpl6">
                        <img src="assets/img/portfolio/portfolio_09.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="">
                        <div class="he-view">
                            <div class="bg a0" data-animate="fadeIn">
                                <h3 class="a1" data-animate="fadeInDown">Motorbikes</h3>
                                <a data-rel="prettyPhoto" href="assets/img/portfolio/portfolio_09.jpg" class="dmbutton a2" data-animate="fadeInUp"><i class="ion-search"></i></a>
                                <a href="single-project.html" class="dmbutton a2" data-animate="fadeInUp"><i class="ion-link"></i></a>
                            </div>
                            <!-- he bg -->
                        </div>
                        <!-- he view -->
                    </div>
                    <!-- he wrap -->
                </div>
                <!-- end col-12 -->
            </div>
            <!-- portfolio -->
        </div>
        <!-- portfolio container -->

        <div class="container mt">
            <div class="row clients centered">
                <p class="mb">Some clients that I had the pleasure to working for.</p>
                <div class="col-sm-2 col-sm-offset-1">
                    <a href="http://racingwithbrad.com/" target="_blank"><img src="assets/img/client1.png" alt=""></a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!--/row-->
        </div>
        <!--/container-->
    </div>
    <!--/.G-->

    <div id="sep">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row centered">
                <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
                    <h1>I live in the amazing United Kingdom</h1>
                    <h3 class="mb">Click the button below to request prices and information about me.</h3>
                    <a href=""><button class="btn btn-conf btn-clear">Request for Information</button></a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!--/row-->
        </div>
        <!--/container-->
    </div>
    <!--/.sep-->

    <div id="f">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row centered">
                <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
                    <p class="white">
                        Copyright © 2016 Jacob Lane Photography.
                    </p>
                </div>
                <!--/col-md-8-->
            </div>
        </div>
        <!--/container-->
    </div>
    <!--/.F-->

    <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
    ================================================== -->
    <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
    <script src="assets/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/retina-1.1.0.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/jquery.hoverdir.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/jquery.hoverex.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/jquery.prettyPhoto.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/jquery.isotope.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/custom.js"></script>


    <script>
        // Portfolio
        (function($) {
            "use strict";
            var $container = $('.portfolio'),
                $items = $container.find('.portfolio-item'),
                portfolioLayout = 'fitRows';

            if ($container.hasClass('portfolio-centered')) {
                portfolioLayout = 'masonry';
            }

            $container.isotope({
                filter: '*',
                animationEngine: 'best-available',
                layoutMode: portfolioLayout,
                animationOptions: {
                    duration: 750,
                    easing: 'linear',
                    queue: false
                },
                masonry: {}
            }, refreshWaypoints());

            function refreshWaypoints() {
                setTimeout(function() {}, 1000);
            }

            $('nav.portfolio-filter ul a').on('click', function() {
                var selector = $(this).attr('data-filter');
                $container.isotope({
                    filter: selector
                }, refreshWaypoints());
                $('nav.portfolio-filter ul a').removeClass('active');
                $(this).addClass('active');
                return false;
            });

            function getColumnNumber() {
                var winWidth = $(window).width(),
                    columnNumber = 1;

                if (winWidth > 1200) {
                    columnNumber = 5;
                } else if (winWidth > 950) {
                    columnNumber = 4;
                } else if (winWidth > 600) {
                    columnNumber = 3;
                } else if (winWidth > 400) {
                    columnNumber = 2;
                } else if (winWidth > 250) {
                    columnNumber = 1;
                }
                return columnNumber;
            }

            function setColumns() {
                var winWidth = $(window).width(),
                    columnNumber = getColumnNumber(),
                    itemWidth = Math.floor(winWidth / columnNumber);

                $container.find('.portfolio-item').each(function() {
                    $(this).css({
                        width: itemWidth + 'px'
                    });
                });
            }

            function setPortfolio() {
                setColumns();
                $container.isotope('reLayout');
            }

            $container.imagesLoaded(function() {
                setPortfolio();
            });

            $(window).on('resize', function() {
                setPortfolio();
            });
        })(jQuery);
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

CSS:

```
/*  ################################################################
    1. GENERAL STRUCTURES
################################################################# */

/* Import fonts */
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,700,900);

@import url("prettyPhoto.css") screen;
@import url("hoverex-all.css") screen;

/* cyrillic-ext */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local('Roboto'), local('Roboto-Regular'), url(http://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v15/ek4gzZ-GeXAPcSbHtCeQI_esZW2xOQ-xsNqO47m55DA.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0460-052F, U+20B4, U+2DE0-2DFF, U+A640-A69F;
}
/* cyrillic */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local('Roboto'), local('Roboto-Regular'), url(http://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v15/mErvLBYg_cXG3rLvUsKT_fesZW2xOQ-xsNqO47m55DA.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0400-045F, U+0490-0491, U+04B0-04B1, U+2116;
}

* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0px;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}
body {
    background: #fff;
    margin: 0;
    color: #5a5a5a;
}

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 300;
}


p {
    padding: 0;
    margin-bottom: 12px;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 300;
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 28px;
    color: #666;
    margin-top: 10px;
}

html,
body {
    height: 100%;
}

.alignleft { float: left; }
.alignright { float: right; }
.aligncenter {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    display: block;
    clear: both;
}
.centered {text-align: center}
.mt {margin-top: 50px;}
.mb {margin-bottom: 50px;}
.mtb {margin-top: 50px; margin-bottom: 50px;}
.mtb2 { margin-top: 100px; margin-bottom: 100px;}
.ptb {padding-top: 80px; padding-bottom: 80px;}

.clear {
    clear: both;
    display: block;
    font-size: 0;
    height: 0;
    line-height: 0;
    width:100%;
}
::-moz-selection  {
    color: #fff;
    text-shadow:none;
    background:#2B2E31;
}
::selection {
    color: #fff;
    text-shadow:none;
    background:#2B2E31;
}
*,
*:after,
*:before {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
a {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    text-decoration: none;
    -webkit-transition: background-color .4s linear, color .4s linear;
    -moz-transition: background-color .4s linear, color .4s linear;
    -o-transition: background-color .4s linear, color .4s linear;
    -ms-transition: background-color .4s linear, color .4s linear;
    transition: background-color .4s linear, color .4s linear;
    color: #1abc9c;
}
a:hover,
a:focus {
  text-decoration: none;
  color:#696E74;
}

.nopadding {
    padding: 0px !important;
    margin: 0px;
}


/* FORM CONFIGURATION */

input {
    font-size: 16px;
    min-height: 40px;
    border-radius: 2px;
    line-height: 20px;
    padding: 11px 30px 12px;
    border: 1px solid #b9b9af;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    background-color: #fff;
    -webkit-transition: background-color 0.2s;
    transition: background-color 0.2s;
}

.white {
        color: #fff;
}

.subscribe-input {
    float: left;
    width: 65%;
    text-align: left;
    margin-right: 2px;
}

.subscribe-submit {
    right: 0;
}

.btn-download {
    background: #FDE3A7;
}

.btn-conf {
    border-radius: 50px;
    margin-right: 15px;
    font-size: 11px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    padding: 14px 28px 13px 28px;
    }

.btn-clear {
    background: transparent;
    color: white;
    border: 2px solid white;
}
.btn-clear:hover {
    background: white;
    color: #2f2f2f;
}



.dmbutton:hover,
.dmbutton:active,
.dmbutton:focus{
    color: #ffffff;
    background-color: #222222;
    border-color: #ffffff;
}
.dmbutton {
    background:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    border: 1px solid #ffffff;
    color: #ffffff;
    -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
    border-radius: 2px;
    padding-top: 1.025rem;
    padding-right: 2.25rem;
    letter-spacing:0.85px;
    padding-bottom: 1.0875rem;
    padding-left: 2.25rem;
    font-size: 1.55rem;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-weight: normal;
    line-height: normal;
    margin: 0 0 1.25rem;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
    -webkit-transition: background-color 300ms ease-out;
    -moz-transition: background-color 300ms ease-out;
    transition: background-color 300ms ease-out;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    font-weight: normal !important;
}

/* HEADER SECTION */
#h {
    background: url(../img/header.jpg) no-repeat center top;
    padding-top: 5px;
    background-attachment: relative;
    background-position: center center;
    min-height: 700px;
    width: 100%;

    -webkit-background-size: 100%;
    -moz-background-size: 100%;
    -o-background-size: 100%;
    background-size: 100%;

    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    color: white;
}

#h .logo {
    margin-top: 30px;
    margin-left: 40px;
    padding-bottom: 150px;
}

#h .logo h3{
    font-weight: 900;
    color: white;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
}

#h3 {
    font-weight: 900;
    color: white;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
}

#h .logo h2{
    font-weight: 900;
    color: white;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
}

#h h3 {
    margin-top: 10px;
}

#h i {
    font-size: 50px;
}

#j {
    padding-bottom: 50px;
}

/* GREY SECTION */
#g {
    padding-top: 50px;
    padding-bottom: 50px;
    background: #f5f5f5;
}

.portfolio {
    padding:0 !important;
    margin:0 !important;
    display:block;
}


.portfolio-item .title:before {border-radius:0; display:none}
.portfolio-item p {margin:0px 0 30px;}
.portfolio-item h3 {margin:-10px 0 10px; font-size:16px; text-transform:uppercase;}


.tpl6 h3
{
    color:#fff;
    margin:0;
    padding:40px 5px 0;
    font-size:16px;
    text-transform:uppercase;
}
.tpl6 .dmbutton
{
    display:inline-block;
    margin:30px 5px 20px 5px;
    font-size:13px;
}

.tpl6 .bg
{
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    background-color:#673AB7;
    background-color:rgba(103,58,183,.9);
    text-align:center;
}

/* CLIENTS */

.clients img {
    max-width: 140px;
    max-height: 60px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.clients .col-sm-2 {
    height: 80px;
    line-height: 80px;
}

/* CONTACT SEPARATOR */
#sep {
    background: url(../img/sep.jpg) no-repeat center top;
    padding-top: 100px;
    background-attachment: relative;
    background-position: center center;
    min-height: 450px;
    width: 100%;
    color: white;

    -webkit-background-size: 100%;
    -moz-background-size: 100%;
    -o-background-size: 100%;
    background-size: 100%;

    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    color: white;
}

#sep h3 {
    font-weight: 300;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
}

/* FOOTER */
#f {
    padding-top: 25px;
    padding-bottom: 25px;
    background-color: #673AB7;
}

#f i {
    margin-right: 30px;
    font-size: 35px;
}

#f a {
    color: white;
}

/* HEADER 2 - PORTFOLIO SECTION */
#h2 {
    background: url(../img/header-2.jpg) no-repeat center top;
    padding-top: 5px;
    background-attachment: relative;
    background-position: center center;
    min-height: 700px;
    width: 100%;

    -webkit-background-size: 100%;
    -moz-background-size: 100%;
    -o-background-size: 100%;
    background-size: 100%;

    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    color: white;
}

#h2 .logo {
    margin-top: 30px;
    margin-left: 40px;
    padding-bottom: 150px;
}

#h2 .logo h2{
    font-weight: 900;
    color: white;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
}

#h2 h3 {
    margin-top: 30px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
}
```

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.   Although you have provided a [**link to an example or site**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it), if the link were to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem.

Comment: We cannot troubleshoot this properly because your PasteBin doesn't have any functional code; there is no way to tell what `assets/css/style.css` is doing, for example.  Bootstrap however DOES have the `text-center` class which can align items to the center of their respective container.

Comment: @RobertC as mentioned above, I'm not good with what you've said, I need code.

Comment: @JacobLane That's a problem.  Stack Overflow is NOT a code-writing service.  Commenters here are more than happy to help you troubleshoot issues, but in order to do that we need to be able to view the code you have written.

Comment: @RobertC is this better? https://jsfiddle.net/2pbc3984/

Comment: When *"I'm not good at this"* means *"Therefore I want to get better at it"*, you are welcome on SO. However, in you case, it means *"I want someone else to do it for me"*. You should consider hiring a professional, rather than asking people to work for you for free. We're here to help you learn and improve your coding skills, not to code for you. It's a a huge difference.

Comment: @JacobLane In the Fiddle you created, your Recent Projects and Companies Worked For sections are centered.  Did you resolve the issue or is there a miscommunication on what needs to be corrected?

Comment: Trying again to close this: _Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself_

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
<div style='text-align:center'>
    You can put an image, text or whatever you want here ... 
</div>
```

Answer (score -3):

I don't understand your question,

you can make a class in css called be centred so:

```
.centered {
position: absolute;
left: 50%;
margin-left: -100px;
}
```

in CSS file you have to put a . before the class name

then in the html file under a tag that you want to center add that class so for example inside the image  that you want to centre or text

that you want to center  you can centre by referring to the class that you made so

```
< p class = centered>
```

or you can use the center tag  around the paragraph you want to be centred so

```
<center> <p> paragraph <p> <center>
```

Comment: Ref: *"I don't understand your question,... "*, you should try to limit your answers to questions you understand. Also, please be kind enough to peruse the SO rules and principles before answering. Thank you.

Comment: The `<center>` tag was deprecated in HTML5 and should not be considered a viable solution for modern HTML/CSS design.